# How do I expand all except for the first parameter to a variadic macro?

Tags: c++, macros, boost-preprocessor

I want to have a macro `MAC(...)` which expands to all except the first argument passed to it. How do I achieve this?

My first thoughts were to convert the `__VA_ARGS__` to a `BOOST_PP_TUPLE` and then do a `POP_FRONT` operation:

```
#define MAC(...)\
  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_POP_FRONT(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))
MAC(1,2,3)
```

But this simply expands to

> BOOST_PP_TUPLE_POP_FRONT((1,2,3))

I tried adding the `BOOST_PP_EXPAND` macro:

```
#define MAC(...)\
  BOOST_PP_EXPAND(\
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_POP_FRONT BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__))
MAC(1,2,3)
```

But I get the same result. What I *want* is an output of

> 2, 3

How do I achieve this?

**Using templates is not an option nor is using other libraries or tools (other than `boost`).**

Comment: What is this for? If you can solve your problem without macro magic, you should do that.

Comment: @NeilKirk That's not an option. The output will be used to generate class names and drive type decisions that can't be done via templates (at least not without templates that would be far nastier than this macro).

Comment: I suggest you use a separate code generator tool. It could even be written in C++, and output the C++ files you need.

Comment: @NeilKirk hmm, that's probably a good suggestion but I don't have that luxury either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the simple answer?

```
#define Y(ignore, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define X(...) Y(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: If X was called with one argument, it will be using the zero-variadic-macro-arguments extension. Ik this is a small nitpick, but it wouldn't be strict standard C++